# How to print text at different locations on the screen itself?

Tags: c, printing, screen, gdi

I would like to know how to print text in random locations on the screen **itself**, not in a console or something else. For example, if you're on the desktop and you run the program, it shows text at random locations with the background being your desktop.

Details:

OS: Windows 10

Edit:

I managed to print text on the screen itself with:

```
_In_ HDC hdcScreen
TextOutW(hdcScreen, rand() % 72 * 83, rand() % 64 * 90, L"text", 9);
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it inside a window of your own? If not, then first learn that. Then do you know how to create transparent or "invisible" windows? If not then learn that next. Then it's the simple matter of combining those two things.

Comment: A standard C solution not possible as `stdout` is a stream and has an insufficient concept of _screen_ aside from line feed and horizontal spacing.  The issue is not an OS one either, but more of a shell and compiler one.  What compiler and what shell? (DOS-like `cmd` window?, Cygwin terminal, etc.)

Comment: @Chux - I think OP is attempting to write to the Windows Desktop as opposed to stdout into a console.

Comment: @ryyker Fair point.  Unless OP details, we are left with guessing.

Comment: A quick Google search for _How to write content to the Windows Desktop using Windows API using C_, may eventually get you to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textouta)

Comment: By modifying the Google query to include the Windows GDI API, I found this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-text)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Looking at examples of screensaver code could show you how.

Comment: @ryyker - Yes, I'm trying to write to the Windows Desktop. I'll read the docs you sent me, thank you!